# Вызов фрагмента настроек из MainActivity

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

создаю фрагмент настроек и не могу его вызвать. Код фрагмента.

```
public class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

@Override
public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
    setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.fragment_preference, rootKey);
}
}
```

Здесь вызываю фрагменты
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
private FrameLayout frameLayout;

private HomeFragment homeFragment;
private AddFragment addFragment;
private SettingsFragment settingsFragment;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.main_nav);
    frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.main_frame);

    homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    addFragment = new AddFragment();
    settingsFragment = new SettingsFragment();

    setFragment(homeFragment);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.nav_home:
                    bottomNavigationView.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.darkTurquise);
                    setFragment(homeFragment) ;
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_add:
                    bottomNavigationView.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.darkTurquise);
                    setFragment(addFragment);
                    return true;
                case R.id.nav_setting:
                    bottomNavigationView.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.darkTurquise);

                    Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentSetting);

                    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    if (savedInstanceState == null){
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentSetting, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    }
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setFragment( android.support.v4.app.Fragment fragment) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

```
Fragment fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragmentSetting);
```

Возвращает null. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: как я понимаю в разметке вашей активити вы добавляете фрагменты в контейнер с id main_frame. Проблема в том, что вы не добавляли settingsFragment во фрагмент менеджер. Вызывайте setFragment(settingsFragment); когда нажимаете на settings вместо текущей реализации

Comment: так же вы исполтзете фрагменты из библиотеки поддержки (support.v4), а фрагмент-менеджер вызываете в некоторых местах из API (getFragmentManager(), а не getSupportFragmentManager()) - нужно привести всю работу с фрагментами к чему то одному, желательно к библиотеке поддержки